# Install Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.5 on Proliant ML150 G2 server

Tags: linux, redhat, hp, hp-proliant

I am investigating if I can install Red Hat Enterprise 5.5 on Proliant ML150 G2 server but I don't know if this configuration is possible.

Is this configuration possible?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't certified. See http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/linux/hplinuxcert.html under the "archive" tab. RHEL3 and RHEL4 are. Also see https://hardware.redhat.com/list.cgi?product=Red+Hat+Hardware+Certification&quicksearch=proliant+ml150

On the other hand, I'd try it and see; most likely it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and it is possible to install this. To verify it you can download an eval copy and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the configuration is possible. However, it sometimes depends upon the particular storage controller installed in the system.

[Take a look at the Quickspecs for the ProLiant ML150 G2.](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12092_na/12092_na.HTML)

It's an 800MHz FSB Pentium Xeon model, so it is an EM64T 64-bit capable processor. RHEL 5 32-bit or 64-bit will install fine on it, regardless of whether it is a SCSI or SATA model.

The standard questions apply, though. This is an old server model. Do you intend to use RAID? Also, why are you specifically looking at the 5.5 release of RHEL? Version 5.8 is available as of this date.